# 403 error for Posting images from /Internal storage/DCIM/camera

Tags: android

I am able to Post images from the following location to the server:

```
/Internal storage/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Images
```

with no issue.

however when I select any image taken with camera from

```
 /Internal storage/DCIM/camera
```

posting goes through with no error and a link for the image appears in the server, but when I click on its link it gives me 403 error. Also In the app the loaded images appear as blank, where the images from WhatsApp folder display correctly.

Is there anything special about this folder?
Is there any permission that I require?
I already have these two permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Comment: You don't need `android.permission.CAMERA` to read image files.

Answer (score 0):

It is odd. turned out that it has to do with the size of the image. My server is in Digital Ocean. I lowered the size of the image and it behaves normally now!